# How to move a div relative to its center(like an anchor point)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchorpoint

When i drag a mouse over a div i want that div to resize after it's center like an anchor point but i don't know how.By default the "anchor point" it's set left-top

Here is an example :

```js
var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
x.onmouseover = function() {
  res_in(this.id);
};
x.onmouseout = function() {
  res_out(this.id);
};

function res_in(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = '70px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.height = '70px';
}

function res_out(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = '100px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.height = '100px';
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *cleanest* way to do this is using `transform`. You can use the `scale` function to resize. The default transform origin is in the middle, but you can change that if you want using css's `transform-origin` property, which works exactly like you describe it - it's an anchor point for the transform.

Also, you don't need the JS that's in your example. Here's a working clean example:

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

#mydiv:hover {
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  -o-transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

**Read more:**

- [MDN `transform-origin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. So many useless `document.getElementById(id), document.getElementById(id)` were hurting my eyes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I combine this with javascript and works

Comment: @Valentin glad to hear, but you don't need javascript for hover if you can do it using CSS. It's just cleaner

Comment: @NonameSL I know, but do a form validation and whem I click(or hover, but in my case click) on a form input a green cercle appear, the input make the cercle to react , i didnt need the cercle to react by itself , but in another cases it's the best as you said

Answer (score 0):

you can increase margin when size decrease. https://jsfiddle.net/sfxLb7en/52/

```
var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
x.onmouseover = function(){res_in(this.id);};
x.onmouseout = function(){res_out(this.id);};
function res_in(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.width = '70px';
document.getElementById(id).style.height = '70px';
document.getElementById(id).style.margin = '15px';
}
function res_out(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.width = '100px';
document.getElementById(id).style.height = '100px';
document.getElementById(id).style.margin = '0px';
}
```

or just use transform:scale() https://jsfiddle.net/sfxLb7en/53/

```
var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
x.onmouseover = function(){res_in(this.id);};
x.onmouseout = function(){res_out(this.id);};
function res_in(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.transform="scale(0.7)";
}
function res_out(id)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.transform="scale(1)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change the margin of the element half as fast as the size:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('mydiv');
x.onmouseover = function() {
  res_in(this.id);
};
x.onmouseout = function() {
  res_out(this.id);
};

function res_in(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = '70px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.height = '70px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.margin = '15px';
}

function res_out(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.width = '100px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.height = '100px';
  document.getElementById(id).style.margin = '0px';
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv">

</div>
```